# Angularstrap Select - long lists cannot scroll on the ipad

Tags: select, scroll, angular-strap

It looks like for long list the dropdown menu cannot be scrolled on an ipad.  How can I make it scrollable?  I have tried to create a template too with no luck.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MbNMZQdnuuvwb0G5amKo?p=preview

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" data-trigger="click" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.